# Backspace/Delete not working in Jquery alphanumeric validation

Tags: jquery, keycode, alphanumeric, backspace

Backspace/Delete not working in **Mozilla Firefox** for  Jquery alphanumeric validation .

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
$("#myTextBox").bind("keypress", function(event) { 
    var charCode = event.which;

    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 
    return /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(keyChar); 
});
```

[click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLaDH/219/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
$("#myTextBox").bind("keypress", function(event) { 
        var charCode = event.which;

        if(charCode == 8 || charCode == 0)
        {
             return;
        }
        else
        {
            var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); 
            return /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(keyChar); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I use this code for delete key ? Is this the correct way of using? `if(charCode == 'undefined'){return; }`